Can you Constrain the Noise Modifier?
I'm trying to use the Noise modifier to animate an object's Z axis. I want the object to move up and down which it is doing with the Noise modifier but I would like to constrain how far down it goes. I could use the scale and strength part of the modifier but I would like to keep the motion in it's frantic state. Is there something I can do to prevent the object from traveling too far down or too far up for that matter?
Thank you!

You could give a Limit Location constraint to your object, or add a Limits modifier and set the Y values as needed:


Not a perfect solution but useful in many cases.  I think I'll submit a right-click suggestion to enhance the noise modifier so that similar to other build-ins (sine, cosine) one can set an amplitude and offset.   My use case is a simple char-mesh mouth-open animation to simulate conversation -- one doesn't want the mouth to peg full-open or full-close (where this solution isn't sufficient)   Yes I could use audio Sound to Sample, but this is more work in a non-audio situation. posted

@james_t yes this is a good idea

Thank you for this.

Thank you for this. I think I should have explained my goal with a few more details. I have a rigged human character and I'm trying to get one leg to go up and down, kind of a repetitive stomping motion, a noise modifier allows me to do this but I would like to control how far up and how far down the stomping action goes. Would this still work with a limit modifier and how exactly would I apply that to the leg? Thank you.

@Bob While noise is a useful feature, it doesn't resemble any stomping motion I know of. You should probably keyframe the stomps, staggered in pseudo-random intervals. And if that looks too mechanical, you can mix in the influence of noise. Using a driver to average between multiple rigged movements is also a possibility, although I hesitate to recommend anything overly complex if a simpler solution will suffice.
